# Using emotes to give roles Discord.js

Tags: discord.js

In my discord server, as a verification method, I want my bot to have all users react to the message and then get given the verified role, and remove the old role. The current code I have doesn't grant or remove roles, but doesn't error.

```
client.on("messageReactionAdd", function(users) {
users.addRole(users.guild.roles.find("name", setup.verify));
users.removeRole(users.guild.roles.find("name", setup.default));
});
```

Comment: What are the values of `setup.verify` and `setup.default`?

Comment: Default & Certified Retro, These Both Work Using Commands

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a problem in the current code. The `messageReactionAdd` event returns a `User` object, which does not contain the property `.guilds` which you attempt to access: `users.guilds.r-` .

Instead of this perhaps you should the `id` of the `User` object and plug that into `message.guild.members.get("id here")`. Then use the returned `Member` object with your current code. That should work!

References:

[Guild Member](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember)
, [Message Reaction Event](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-messageReactionAdd), [User Object](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User)

Answer (score 2):

Would something like this work?
I'm not sure it will I haven't tested it. This should add the role if the message they reacted to consists of the word "role1" and if they react to a different message it will remove the role. I don't know if this is what you're going for but in theory this should work.

```
 client.on("MessageReactionAdd", function(users) {
if (message.content === "role1") {
  users.addRole(users.guild.roles.find("name", setup.verify))
} else if (!message.content === "role1") {
  user.removeRole(users.guild.role.find("name", setup.default))
}
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Are the names of the roles; setup.verify & setup.default?
If not, that's why it is not working.

Try:

```
client.on("messageReactionAdd", function(users) {
users.addRole(users.guild.roles.find("id", ROLEIDHERE));
users.removeRole(users.guild.roles.find("id", ROLEIDHERE));
});
```

where ROLEIDHERE put the `role id` to find the role id just tag the role and before you hit send put \ before the tag and it will supply the id