# Discord.py React Roles

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to set up reaction roles but am not sure how I can read weather a user reacted or unreacted. This bot is for a set discord so I can input the message id and that. I want to see how I can have multiple reactions on the same message! Let me know if you can direct me anywhere!

Comment: Use `on_reaction_add` or `on_raw_reaction_add` events. There are so many question like that, you could at least make an effort and google your question. Even the library itself has an example for the thing you're looking for, [link here](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/reaction_roles.py)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using emotes to give roles Discord.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48033935/using-emotes-to-give-roles-discord-js)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Issue adding a role when reacting to a post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55225017/issue-adding-a-role-when-reacting-to-a-post)